# can't run program in RedHat

Tags: c, linux, redhat

I wrote some simple program

```
int main(){
              printf("hello word!");
              return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc -o hello hello.c` (no errors)
but when I run it `in terminal` using `./hello` I see nothing, why? thanks in advance

Comment: That should not compile, technically you need `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: there is no need, otherwise I would receive an error.

Comment: "hello WORD" hahaha

Comment: C is quite tolerant, unlike C++.

Comment: IMHO gcc will raise just a warning if -Wall was specified

Comment: I know all that, its just that it shouldn't compile if you are compiling correctly, namely with `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: On my Mac OS X, without include and no further flags it just raise a warning: foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, and should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @razlebe The question is "can't run program in RedHat". This could be a possible reason why considering using a decent compilation procedure, it would give an error.

Comment: @mathepic No, sorry - he says he compiles and runs the program.

Comment: @razlebe What if he compiled a different program before, edited it, recompiled, and didn't notice the error? (We can also note that there might be an overridden alias for gcc that includes -Wall and -Werror.

Comment: @mathepic Then at the point where we determine that, I'd withdraw my objection. :)

Comment: The most amusing this to me is that there were several other posts with the same answer and mine is the only one that got downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be the missing newline, so that the output is mangled with the next prompt.

Try:

```
printf("hello world\n");
```

this version also uses a more conventional message.

Comment: The trailing '\n' is completely irrilevant for the sake of being displayed something

Comment: @thesp0nge could it cause the buffer to not be flushed on some systems?

Comment: Actually this all depends on your shell. On my zsh, nothing would be *visible* on the screen unless it has a newline

Comment: mmmh I don't think so... on Snow Leopard it just run and display the message... maybe you want to add fflush(stdout); before the return but I don't think this is the problem

Comment: @Adam this is strange, I can't reproduce on Snow Leopard with zsh too :-(

Comment: @thesp0nge: Not true. The standard library specification clearly says that the trailing `\n` might be *required* on some systems.

Comment: @AndreyT thank you for pointing this out, I wasn't aware about it!

Comment: @AndreyT: Irrelevant because this is not plain C but an implementation which claims/attempts to conform to POSIX, where no such liberty is granted (text and binary streams are required by POSIX to behave identically).

Comment: +1 for "uses a more conventional message" - it made me laugh. :-)

Comment: @R, the lack of a newline _will_ cause it to not advance to the next line, though, and shells have been known to erase this line before printing the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Add \n to your printed string so the output buffer get flushed into you terminal.

```
printf("hello world!\n");
```

Moreover you should include stdio header to avoid implicit references

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it does output a message but then the app terminates immediately and you are unable to see it.

After displaying the message, call a function that reads the next keystroke to prevent the app from terminating until you press a key.

Answer (score 0):

include stdio.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and try to flush the stdout

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Perhaps the standard output buffer hasn't been flushed. Remember also that if a C program is interrupted, it is possible that some printf has been called successfully, but the buffer hasn't been flushed so you don't see anything. If you want to be certain that a printf has been called correctly, then manually flush the output.

Comment: `fflush` on program exit is part of the C standard. There is no need to call it explicitly.

Comment: @R.. : thats not true. If the program crash after dereferencing a null pointer, for example, may happen that some data remain into the output buffer, and don't be print even if the code execution reached the printf instruction .

Comment: That's not the case in this program. Dereferencing a null pointer, by the way, invokes UB, so the standard says *nothing* about what happens in a program which does so. Even if you call `printf`, then `fflush`, then `*(volatile char *)0=0;`, it's still possible there is no output, because UB affects **all** program output, both before and after the point where UB is invoked.

Comment: @R.. : you are right. I've said that to him, just to pointing out that not always when you don't see text in the screen, the printf hasn't been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The `#include <stdio.h>` is missing. You should have received a warning message like: `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’`. Then depending on the system you could get or not the output you wanted.

Comment: He clearly says he compiles and runs the program, so this can't be the problem (on this occasion).

Comment: And it compiles. But the warning should be there, because it is a implicit declaration. And most probably the print appears mixed with somthing else. A '\n' is indeed advisable, but the #include is a must

Answer (score 0):

The specification of the C language states that the last line of output in a text stream *might* require the `\n` at the end. The language states that this requirement is *implementation-defined*. This immediately means that in general case the behavior of the program is not defined if its line of output to a text stream does not have a `\n` at the end.

The behavior becomes defined only when you are talking about some specific implementation. Some implementation might produce output. Some other implementation might produce nothing. And yet another implementation might behave in some other way.

For your specific implementation (GCC on Linux) I'd expect to see the output even without the trailing `\n`. Maybe there's something about the way your shell/terminal is set up that makes it invisible.

Comment: POSIX requires the output regardless of whether `\n` is printed. The issue is merely zsh clobbering over it on the terminal.